# How to handle NULL-value on SSQLAlchemy composite()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following ORM structure:

```
class ParamWrapper:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def __composite_values__(self):
        return self.param


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game'
    game_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    raw_param = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True)
    param = composite(ParamWrapper, raw_param)
```

How can I make it so that if `raw_param is None`, then also `param is None`.

Comment: What is it now with this setup?

Comment: Currently it is `param = ParamWrapper(None)`

Comment: I don't think you can do that with composite class, as param is always an instance of ParamWrapper. You can do it with hybrid properties. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *hybrid_property* to solve this, as you need a conditional. Composite always returns the composite class. If the return value needs to be None instead of ParamWrapper(None), the only way is to branch somewhere.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
...
class ParamWrapper:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def __composite_values__(self):
        return self.param


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game'
    game_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    raw_param = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True)
    param_raw = composite(ParamWrapper, raw_param)

    @hybrid_property
    def param(self):
        return self.param_raw if self.raw_param is not None else None
```

This makes your Game.param either an instance of ParamWrapper or None.

The usefulness of this can be debated, as you need to access foo.param.param to get the actual value from a query result object. If foo.param is None, this fails with an exception.  You can of course modify the hybrid property to return self.param_raw.param instead if you are only interested in the contents of the object and not the object itself. Then you would have either this or None but never an exception.

Hannu